# Flutter TextField - How to support submission on <ENTER> _and_ newline on <SHIFT-ENTER>

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm working on a Flutter Web application which includes chat.

I'd like to include an ordinary input function where users can enter text and send it into the chat stream. A standard feature of chat apps these days is to `send` on `<ENTER>` and to perform a line break on `<SHIFT-ENTER>`, or some variation of this.

Currently I've only been able to achieve *one* of these functions at a time. If you set the `TextField`'s `keyboardType` to `TextInputType.multiline` then `<ENTER>` and `<SHIFT-ENTER>` always perform a line-break, there doesn't appear to be a way to override this behavior.

If instead your `TextField` is `TextInputType.text` you can capture `<ENTER>` and send, but trying to capture `<SHIFT-ENTER>` to add a line-break has not worked. I've tried manually grabbing the key press via an `onKey` handler and inserting `\n` to the `controller.text`, but it appears that `TextInputType.text` is not meant for multiline at all, so it doesn't play well.

Just wondering if any other devs have run into this or come up with any suitable solutions. Ideally a solution would also work across android/ios. For me, I've decided to go with `TextInputType.text` and forgo the multiline functionality for now.

Thanks

Comment: relate to this issue: [Proposal: Multiline TextField should support both submit and enter a newline](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95985)

Answer (score 16):

This can be achieved by adding a `FocusNode` to the `TextField`. Place the focus node in your widget's state.

```
late final _focusNode = FocusNode(
  onKey: (FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent evt) {
    if (!evt.isShiftPressed && evt.logicalKey.keyLabel == 'Enter') {
      if (evt is RawKeyDownEvent) {
        _sendMessage();
      }
      return KeyEventResult.handled;
    }
    else {
      return KeyEventResult.ignored;
    }
  },
);
```

In your `build` function add the focus when creating the `TextField`.

```
TextField(
  autofocus: true,
  controller: _textController,
  focusNode: _focusNode,
)
```

Comment: very working answer without any additional widget

Comment: greatest answer

Comment: I think it's opposite to ops request, he wants shift+enter to change line, and enter to send message, it can enter, but how baout change new line?

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, I was able to concoct a reasonable solution that I'll post below in case anyone runs into this themselves.

I wrapped the Textfield in a keyboard listener which calls my `onSend` function when it see's an `<Enter>`. I tried this before, but I guess earlier I was missing the cast to `RawKeyEventDataWeb` which allowed me to capture `isShiftPressed` to allow for new lines on `<SHFT-ENTER>` without forcing a send. Unfortunately I had to add some hacky code to remove the `\n` that's added when pressing enter, but that's a small price to pay for functional + modern messaging.

```
RawKeyboardListener(
   focusNode: focusNode,
   onKey: handleKeyPress,
   child: TextField(
        controller: messageController,
        minLines: 1,
        maxLines: null,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        style: normalTextStyle,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
             isDense: true,
             hintText: 'Type a message',
             hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: Color(0xFF474749),
             ),
             border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
    ),
)

void handleKeyPress(event) {
if (event is RawKeyUpEvent && event.data is RawKeyEventDataWeb) {
  var data = event.data as RawKeyEventDataWeb;
  if (data.code == "Enter" && !event.isShiftPressed) {
    final val = messageController.value;
    final messageWithoutNewLine =
        messageController.text.substring(0, val.selection.start - 1) +
            messageController.text.substring(val.selection.start);
    messageController.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: messageWithoutNewLine,
      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: messageWithoutNewLine.length),
      ),
    );
    _onSend();
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I am using in my `TextField` to support newline on enter.

```
class TextInputsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController chatTextFieldController = TextEditingController();
  late final _focusNode = FocusNode(
    onKey: _handleKeyPress,
  );

  KeyEventResult _handleKeyPress(FocusNode focusNode, RawKeyEvent event) {
    // handles submit on enter
    if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) && !event.isShiftPressed) {
      _sendMessage();
      // handled means that the event will not propagate
      return KeyEventResult.handled;
    }
    // ignore every other keyboard event including SHIFT+ENTER
    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (chatTextFieldController.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
      // Do something with your input text
      print(chatTextFieldController.text.trim());

      // bring focus back to the input field
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        _focusNode.requestFocus();
        chatTextFieldController.clear();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: null,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
        autofocus: true,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        controller: chatTextFieldController,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0),
          hintText: "Enter your message here",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are mainly 3 key changes

- `keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,`
- `textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,`
- `FocusNode` which can listen to keyboard events

Answer (score 1):

The best way to have the `Enter` key be disabled for the input and instead send it when no `ctrl` key is pressed is through the focusNode directly on the input, this way you won't have to remove extra new lines.

```
class _InputTextState extends State<InputText> {
  late final _focusNode = FocusNode(onKey: handleKeyPress);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      focusNode: _focusNode,
    );
  }

  KeyEventResult handleKeyPress(FocusNode focusNode, RawKeyEvent event) {
    // handles submit on enter
    if (kIsWeb &&
        event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) &&
        !event.isControlPressed &&
        !event.isShiftPressed) {
      widget.onSubmit();
    // handled means that the event will not propagate
      return KeyEventResult.handled;
    }
    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution if you want to use `onKeyEvent` instead of `onKey`. Since `onKey` will be deprecated at one point according to the documentation:

`This is a legacy API based on [RawKeyEvent] and will be deprecated in the future. Prefer [onKeyEvent] instead.`

```
// In State class
FocusNode? textFieldNode;

@override
void initState() {
  textFieldNode = FocusNode(
    onKeyEvent: (node, event) {
      final enterPressedWithoutShift = event is KeyDownEvent &&
          event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.enter &&
          !HardwareKeyboard.instance.physicalKeysPressed.any(
                (key) => <PhysicalKeyboardKey>{
              PhysicalKeyboardKey.shiftLeft,
              PhysicalKeyboardKey.shiftRight,
            }.contains(key),
          );

      if (enterPressedWithoutShift) {
        // Submit stuff
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      } else if (event is KeyRepeatEvent) {
        // Disable holding enter
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      } else {
        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
      }
    },
  );
  super.initState();
}
```

In Widget:

```
TextField(
  focusNode: textFieldNode,
)
```